# How to add listeners to widget column dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am preparing one column object and adding in my grid. This way.

`myGrid.setColumns(myColumns);`

Here is how my column code look like.

```
var myColumns = [  {
      "header":"myCol1",
      "dataIndex":"myCol1",
      "flex":1
   },{
      "header":"myCol2",
      "dataIndex":"myCol2",
      "flex":1,
   },{
    "xtype":"widgetcolumn",
     "header":"myCol3",
     "dataIndex":"myCol2",
     "flex":1,
     "widget": {
     "xtype": "numberfield",
     "decimalPrecision" :5,
     "minValue": 0,
     "bind": "{record.appliedQty}"
    }
  }
  ]
```

In `myCol3` I have widget column, I want to apply `blur` event in `myCol3`.
Now here is my grid. Can anybody help me how to give `blur` option in my grid  for the column.

Here is how i am defining my grid.

```
var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                columns: [],
                height: "300px",
                plugins: [{
                    ptype: 'rowexpandergrid', // This is grid which appear on expand of row. 
                    gridConfig: [{
                        columns: [],
                        autoWidth: true,
                        autoHeight: true,
                    }]
                }],

                store: myStore
                selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                    listeners: {
                        select: function (_this, record, index, eOpts) {
                            // Some action happening here.
                        },
                        deselect: function (_this, record, index, eOpts) {
                            // Some action happenin here.

                        }
                    }
                })
            },
            me.gridConfig[0],
    );
```

Comment: Do you want `blur` listener exactly the entire column, not just the column header? Or what difficulties did you have?

Comment: I have updated my code, In widget column i want to apply blur event.

Comment: Do you want to add a listener on the name of the column or the widgets inside it? The standard blues listener for the column component only works for the header, unfortunately.